# Subscribe to answers by email as default

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, questions

Features request: It would be nice if I could set a preference so that by default I would always subscribe by email daily to answers for my questions. It tick the box by default.

Comment: Status declined? Could whoever set that tag elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature seems to have been rejected due to worries about user's setting it and then having trouble turning it off and thinking this site is spam.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably not going to see that checkbox marked by default any time soon.

That would be having you opt-in automatically which is kind of a spammy thing to do. For you to check that box yourself, not so much, since the decision for emails to be sent to you has been made by you and not left by the system to make you later opt-out.

Comment: Does it hurt, if there is a user based preference and the user decides to spam himself with email notifications? It could be turned off at any time, and the default in the user preferences would be unchecked.

Comment: You seem to be answering a question that you invented.  Casebash requested a preference that could be set to make this the default option.  You would have to opt-in for this behavior to take place.

Comment: And then they'll forget that they set it in the first place and come back asking, why is SOFU spamming me?

Comment: If that happens that's a different animal entirely.  I don't necessarily support this request, but I do object to your unapologetic rejection of the idea based on your apparent misunderstanding of the request.

Comment: That's entirely valid.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to get updated when the question you posed gets answers, that is already built in as the default.  You get notified (the envelope next to your username changes color) and you can see links to the answers on your Recent Activity page (accessible via that same envelope icon).

Comment: I think he means the "Notify [email] of new answers daily". He wants that to be checked by default, or at least have a profile setting where that is checked by default.

Comment: Exactly what I meant

Comment: @akf, even though that wasn't the question, your response was still useful!